# Fast way to display huge text file in Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

My Android app displays a huge text file as a simple scroll-able page.
Currently I use a `TextView` embedded within a `ScrollView`, and it is terribly slow since the whole `TextView` is loaded into memory at once although only a small fraction of the text is visible at any given time.

I realize that it is possible to use a `ListView`and build an adapter to load only parts of the text, but that also feels like a sub-optimal hack since I do not want to see any visible borders or unwanted line breaks between such list items.

Is there any easy way to display a huge text file, maybe a library?

Comment: you can remove Listview's lines, actualy you can make it look like one long text just like textVIew and it will be faster

Comment: i agree with ListView - i did it in just 20 lines of code and it looks like one big TextView - no difference at all

Comment: of course it will depend on the size of your text: if it is several MBs stored in some file you would need  `android.util.LruCache` + `RandomAccessFile` approach since it would be impossible to store all of your data in the ram

Comment: The file is not that large (a few hundred kilobytes), I can store it in RAM with ease,  but it is too large for TextViews, I think I will just implement the listview adapter

Comment: so [this](https://pastebin.com/m888vaHh) is an adapter you can start from